# Tabela do DB não acessível

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma classe associativa (FluxoUsuario) entre Usuario e Fluxo, onde FluxoUsuario contém permissões dos usuários para Fluxo, para saber quem pode acessar determinado fluxo, devo ir nessa associativa.

Problema: ao tentar fazer...

```
db.FluxoUsuario.toList();
```

...o VS não reconhece FluxoUsuario mesmo eu podendo acessar os dados no Server Explorer.

**FluxoUsuario.cs:**

```
namespace ProjetoASPNETMVC.Models
{
    public class FluxoUsuario
    {
        [Key]
        public int fluxoUsuarioID { get; set; }
        public int FluxoID { get; set; }
        public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
        public TipoPermissao TipoPermissao { get; set; }

        public virtual Fluxo Fluxo { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TipoPermissao { Ler, LerEscrever }
}
```

**Fluxo.cs:**

```
namespace ProjetoASPNETMVC.Models
{
    public class Fluxo
    {
        [Key]
        public int FluxoID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dê um nome a fluxo")]
        [Display(Name = "Título")]
        public String Nome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Dono do fluxo")]
        public virtual Usuario Dono { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Topico")]
        public String TopicoPertencente { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Visibilidade")]
        public String Visibilidade { get; set; }

        public ICollection<FluxoUsuario> UsuariosPermitidos { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Informacao> Informacoes { get; set; }

        public object[] UsuarioID { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

**Usuario.cs:**

```
namespace ProjetoASPNETMVC.Models
{
    public class Usuario
    {
        [Key]
        public int IDUser { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage = "Informe um Email válido")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Preencha o email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Preencha a senha")]
        [Display(Name = "Senha")]
        public string Senha { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirme a senha")]
        [Compare("Senha", ErrorMessage = "As senhas digitadas não são iguais.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Preencha o nome")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<FluxoUsuario> FluxosPermitidos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possivelmente faltou mapear o `DbSet` no contexto:

```
public DbSet<FluxoUsuario> FluxosUsuario { get; set; }
```

Procure usar nomes de `DbSet` no plural para diferenciar o `DbSet` da classe do *Model*:

```
db.FluxosUsuario.toList();
```